# How to find the probability distribution of a two-variable metric?

Tags: normal-distribution, distributions

I have a certain metric $f(x,y) \in [-1, 1]$. I would like to study the metric assuming $x$ and $y$ are random variables. The input variables are typically normally distributed in most applications of the metric $f$, so I could assume that.

I realize one way to look at this is draw random numbers, and see how the metric behaves. However, it would be really nice to find a closed form solution.

Given the function $f$, is it possible to obtain its probability distribution? I was thinking would something like $\int\int f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}x\ \mathrm{d}y$ be the solution?

I am not very experienced in mathematics or statistics.

Comment: If you want a closed form expression for the density of $f(X, Y)$ then you would need to know the precise distributions of $X$ and $Y$.  Are you willing to assume $X$ and $Y$ are *exactly* normal?  Also, do you have an expression for $f$?

Comment: By definition, the distribution function of $f(X,Y)$ is $F(z)=\Pr(f(X,Y)\le z)$. When $X$ and $Y$ have density functions $\phi$ and $\eta$, respectively, this can be expressed via an indicator function $I$ as an integral $$F(z)=\iint_{f(x,y)\le z} \phi(x)\eta(y)dxdy=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}I(f(x,y)\le z)\phi(x)\eta(y)dxdy.$$ Whether it has a "closed form expression" depends on what you would accept as "closed" and on exactly what $f$ is, so if you want any kind of specific answer you will need to include those details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, you must generate all values of $f(x,y)$, then put them in bins $[f,f+\Delta f]$. This will give you the distribution of $f$. This is very common in finance, it's called [value-at-risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk), where you have a bunch of factors $x,y,\dots$ which impact your losses $f(x,y,\dots)$. The loss is a single dollar number, while factors are all kinds of things like stock market indices, commodity prices etc.